# what type of magento 2 installation method should I choose?

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2.

Following the official tutorials, I've found that there are 3 methods to install Magento 2: "Easy Installation", "Integrator, Packager", and "Contributor Developer".

Here is the link listing those 3 methods:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html

What I want to do is to develop a new extension for my company.

Knowing this, what type of installation method should I choose?
The docs are not clear about that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Composer + command line or Setup Wizard. [Integrator Install](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html) has the following advantages:

- Enables you to reuse third-party libraries without bundling them with source code
- Component-based architecture with robust dependency management
  Manages dependencies to reduce extension conflicts and compatibility issues
- Versioned dependencies
- Semantic versioning
- Supports the PHP Framework Interoperability standard